# how to I create a Luau type that contains a key that requires quoting?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'd like to be able to create a type that has a field invalid characters in it. With a table, I can do this:

```lua
local Element = {
  ["$$typeof"] = 31337,
}
```

with Roblox Luau types, I can't do this:

```lua
type Element = {
  ["$$typeof"]: number,
}
```

How can I strongly type that field of my Element table, without resorting to use of `any`?

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2022, you *can* do this in Roblox Lua and in the open-source Luau parser and runtime v0.523 or later.

Element.lua

```lua
--!strict

export type Element = {
  ["$$typeof"]: number,
  render: (self: Element, x: number, y: number) -> ()
}
local myElement: Element = {
  ["$$typeof"] = 31337,
  render = function(self, a, b) end
}
```

Note that:
The source file requiring Element.lua doesn't have to be strict-mode enabled, but if you want type checking on the consumption of these strong types, you should favor strict mode, whenever practical, across all your source files.